# VSC Flutter - parameter named not recognizable

Tags: flutter

Here is my method:

```
Future<String> guardaExplicacao({Hour hour, Student student, String subject, String meet}) async {

    String _url = '$_apiURL/put_explicacao';
    
    Map _body = {
      'fk_hour': hour.toString(),
      'fk_student': student.toString(),
      'subject': subject,
      'meet': meet
    };

    http.Response response = await http.post(_url, body:_body);
    
    return response.body;
  }
```

In VSC when I write the code:

```
String resultado = await guardaExplicacao(
                    hour: _hour, 
                    student: _student, 
                    subject: _subject, 
                    meet: _meet);
```

VSC complains with the message:

> the named parameter 'meet' isn't defined.

and I don't know why...

Comment: try to restart vscode also can you show how you have declared ```_meet```?

Comment: String  _meet  =  meet ?  "1" :  "0" ;

Comment: Well the syntax seems correct to me do you have flutter and dart plugin installed?

Comment: Thank you for your interest and help. The situation I reported happens to any static method that is created. I simplified the code a little by not saying that GuardaExplicacao was a static method of the Explicacao class. I solved the situation by instantiating the class Explicacao and calling the method getExplicacao.

Comment: great in case you solved it please add the appropriate solution as an aswer to this question as this might help others who might face a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

The situation I reported happens to any static method that is created. I simplified the code a little by not saying that GuardaExplicacao was a static method of the Explicacao class. I solved the situation by instantiating the class Explicacao and calling the method getExplicacao.